# Pasting VBA Array returns #NA after a certain row

Tags: arrays, vba, excel

I'm using the following code to paste an array into a sheet:

```
Worksheets("Name").Range("B2").Resize(Row, 2).Value = WorksheetFunction.Transpose(TempKey)
```

It works fine until row 30233, after which point all remaining values are pasted as "#NA". The values are fine within the array, so it is an issue with the pasting itself. Am I missing something?

Comment: How big is the array? If it's over 65536 rows, and you're using 2013 or 2016, `Transpose` will truncate it without warning.

Comment: So how do I get around it? Any ideas?

Comment: Manually transpose it...

Comment: Or build it transposed if that's an option.

Comment: That would require for loops, making the entire code several times slower. :(

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To transpose by direct code, you can use a simple function like this:

```
Public Function TansP(var As Variant) As Variant
  Dim outP() As Variant, i As Long, j As Long
  ReDim outP(LBound(var, 2) To UBound(var, 2), LBound(var, 1) To UBound(var, 1))
  For i = LBound(outP) To UBound(outP)
    For j = LBound(var) To UBound(var)
      outP(i, j) = var(j, i)
    Next
  Next
  TansP = outP
End Function
```

then all you need, would be `Worksheets("Name").Range("B2").Resize(Row, 2).Value = TransP(TempKey)`

and no... it should not be much slower this way... ;)

Comment: Thanks a bunch, sir.